# How to display a messages in jquery/ajax while the request is being processed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML page that calls a JavaScript method once the document is ready. However i want to display like a refresh status while it gets loaded is there a way i can do it ?

Also the getDonars() method makes a Ajax call to the server while it waits for the response i want to display a status saying processing how do i achieve that ?

Because i have experienced slight delay on my server calls and then if you open the page it looks like there is nothing in there but after couple of second the data pops up. Is there a better approach to my problem ?

javascript code

```
function getDonars() {

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { 
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

          document.getElementById("donars").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

      }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.xyz.com/cfv/getDonars.php", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Html Code

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
           getDonars();

      });
</script>
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" >

      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" >
        <h3 align="center"><B>Donar List </B></h3>
             <div data-role="fieldcontain" >
                <div id="donars"></div>
            </div>
       </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `onreadystatechanged` event you could check `xmlhttp.readyState`

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState < 4) {
  showLoadingMessage()
}
```

of cause you would have to write `showLoadingMessage()` to show a message/image/pink fluffy chicken.

when `xmlhttp.readystate == 4` you would want to hide your message/image/pink fluffy chicken.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<div class="loading_msg" style="display:none">Processing</div>
```

Try using `beforeSend` and `complete` settings of `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.example.com/cfv/getDonars.php",
    beforeSend:function(){
             $(".loading_msg").show();
        },
    complete:function(){
             $(".loading_msg").hide();
        }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have all the answers that you need 
http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want to achieve is to display a message to user while waiting for response from server. JQuery Plugin BloukUI can suit your need really well. Please have a look at the third example of Blue Overlay from their demo page: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Jquery Get to do this. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/5NyLb/)

```
<style>
.loading{
    margin:20% 40%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:2px solid #444;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loading").fadeOut(0);   



        $(".loading").html("<center><img src='images/waiting.gif'><br>Loading...</center>");

            $(".loading").fadeIn(0);
            $.get("http://www.xyz.com/cfv/getDonars.php", { 

            })
            .done(function(data) {
                $("#donars").html(data);
                $(".loading").fadeOut(200); 

            }).fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
            });

});
<script>
```